# Filter table based on multiple columns' value with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### What I am trying to achieve:

I currently got two working buttons with a static `value` which is `Yes`.

```
<button type="button" id="foo_btn" value="Yes" class="btn">Foo</button>
<button type="button" id="bar_btn" value="Yes" class="btn">Bar</button>
```

When clicked it will filter a table based on the column's value and only show the rows which has the value `Yes` in that specific column in them.

Currently I use an switch statement to check the id of the button clicked and then set a variable which determines what column to be filtered, but I don't like this approach as if I include several columns/buttons, it will get rather long and messy. Also I don't like working with `switch` statements.

I also tested the performance of each event in `Developer Tools` in the `Perfomance` section and noticed that each task takes over a second to perform. Is there any superior solution to this rather than using `switch` statements?

#### Working example of what I've tried but with an ugly approach:

```js
$('#foo_btn, #bar_btn').on('click', function() {
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    switch(this.id) {
    case 'foo_btn': 
      col = 'td:nth-child(1)';
      break;
    case 'bar_btn': 
      col = 'td:nth-child(2)';
      break;
    }
    $(col).filter(function() {
      $('tr:not(:has(th))').show();
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val);
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="foo_btn" value="Yes" class="btn">Foo</button>
<button type="button" id="bar_btn" value="Yes" class="btn">Bar</button>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Foo</th>
    <th>Bar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Comment

I feel like this is a really simple solution to a simple problem which I've just gotten my brain tangled in. I appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you post a working example of your code - including the table.

Comment: @obscure No problem. Added working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the working example in your question you could make use of the html **data** property and bake the desired column right into the button itself.
e.g.

```
<button type="button" id="foo_btn" value="Yes" data-column="1" class="btn">Foo</button>
```

and inside the click event listener's callback function you can get the value of `data-colum` using

```
col = 'td:nth-child(' + $(this).data('column') + ')';
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
$('#foo_btn, #bar_btn').on('click', function() {
  var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  col = 'td:nth-child(' + $(this).data('column') + ')';
  $(col).filter(function() {
    $('tr:not(:has(th))').show();
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val);
  }).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="foo_btn" value="Yes" data-column="1" class="btn">Foo</button>
<button type="button" id="bar_btn" value="Yes" data-column="2" class="btn">Bar</button>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Foo</th>
    <th>Bar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What a neat and clean approach! Much appreciated. I didn't even think of taking use of the HTML `data` property. Learning something new everyday, thank you kind stranger. Is there anyway to improve the perfomance of this for a table with over 500 rows? I guess the only approach would have be to avoid doing DOM manipulations? (Not looking for a complete code-answer, just curious.)

Comment: No problem Sanguinary - glad I could help =) Unfortunately I'm not aware of a more performant way. I might be wrong but I think the way you're doing it is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

may be this solution would fit for you?

```js
function getColumnIndex(colName) {
  var headerCell = $('.table tr:first-child() > th:contains(' + colName + ')')
  return headerCell.length ? (headerCell.index() + 1) : -1
}

function showOnlyValues(columnName, valueToShow) {
  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(columnName)

  $('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').filter(function() {
        $('tr:not(:has(th))').show();
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(valueToShow);
    }).parent().hide();
}

$('.filterBtn').on('click', function() {
  var clickedBtn = $(this);
  showOnlyValues(clickedBtn.data('columnName'), clickedBtn.val().toLowerCase());
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" value="Yes" class="btn filterBtn" data-column-name="Foo">Foo</button>
<button type="button" value="Yes" class="btn filterBtn" data-column-name="Bar">Bar</button>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
        <th>Bar</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>No</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! :) While this is working as intended, the code will get really repetitive if I decide to add multiple buttons or columns in the future. I've updated my question with a working example of what I've tried, but this is using a `switch` statement and I'm wondering if there's any solution superior to my approach.

Comment: @Sanguinary I've updated my snippet. Removed using IDs for buttons and double event subscribing. But of course it depends on your future plans. I'd recommend adding column index to the button instead of the name.

Comment: Cleaner approach, but since I don't think I will need the use of those functions in the future for anything else than this purpose, I believe the code is still a bit excessive. I've accepted @obscure 's answer but I do like this approach as well and will definitely be useful for future-readers. I gave you an upvote. :)